# how to add html in middle of a page build with a page builder

Tags: html, elementor, divi

I want to ask how can I add HTML to an elementor page. like I'm building a page using elementor and in the middle of page, I need to build a section which I'm not able to build by elementor nor I can use any plugins so I need to use plain HTML there. let's say I need to add a slick slider in the middle of a page that is created by elementor okay? so I don't want to use any plugins for that and if I insert HTML block in it and type HTML and let's say I need to write a lot of HTML then what to do? or if I need to use HTML block there and on changing HTML it will add extra p tags it br tags in it so how to tackle it
how to add HTML then which don't add extra tags on changing several times
how to add HTML in middle of page which also be a good approach

Comment: you can go into your `functions.php` and create a function there with all the HTML you need. Then make it a shortcode using the WP add_shortcode(); and then add an Elementor shortcode widget and insert your shortcode there

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. You need to use Elementor object called "`HTML`".
You just drag this item inside of section or whatever and just write code there.